# why the submit block is never reached when i click button inside form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am creating a chat application in nodejs.

in the index.html file where i set up the interface for the users to send their messages i define the following form:

```
<form id="chat-form" name="chat-form">
     <input type="text" name="chat-input" id="chat-input" placeholder="type message">
     <br>
     <input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

and inside the `<head> </head>` tags i use the following script:

```
$('#chat-form').submit(function(e){
    console.log("inside the submit");
});
```

Although this code was expected to work, the submit code is never reached.

Comment: put your code in document.ready like $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#chat-form').submit(function(e){
    console.log("inside the submit");
});
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling your code in the `head` then the code gets run before you html gets rendered, so at that point the html form wont exist.

A general best practice is to put your javascript code at the bottom of you file, just before the closing `body` tag and/or to run it in a dom ready function.

```
$(function(){ [code]});
```

Any code ran in the above function will run once the dom has loaded, so your html **will** exist at that point.

```
$(function(){
    $('#chat-form').submit(function(e){
        console.log("inside the submit");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx. This did it. Can you provide an explanation on why this has to be like this? i can search online of course but it will be more explanatory.

Comment: @JoãoMartins what is unclear in _you are calling your code in the head so the html form doesn't exist at that point_?

Comment: @Regent he just said run it in the function.... He then edited the question. stackoverflow users are so agressive. man. relax

Comment: @Regent to be fair I think the OP comment was added in between my initial answer and my editing to give a bit more info.

Comment: @atmd for all that I saw, cited phrase was there before the comment. Nevertheless, the biggest problem is that people neither learn jQuery basics, nor search for the solution of their problem in the Internet. It's definitely abnormal to see many same questions every day. `document.ready`, delegated event handlers and ajax asynchronous execution are top 3.

Comment: Agreed. the same questions do get asked a lot. But I think the problem is that people dont know what they are asking. for example, in this one, the question is "submit block is never reached" they op doesn't know he's asking about running code on document.ready. It's not the same questions that are being asked over and over, its just the same answers.

Comment: @atmd thx a lot for understanding my position and providing me with the correct answer